# PHP's Dot Equals `.=` operator in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, operators

How can you use PHP's Dot Equals `.=` operator in Javascript?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are mentioning is a [**contatenation equals operator**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_Operators#PHP_Assignment_Operators) which sets the value of the left hand operand to a string containing a concatenation of its value appended with the string in the right hand operand.

You can do the same operation in javascript using the `+=` operator.

```
var str = "test";

str += " appended string";
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the `.=` operator is used for string concatenation?

In Javascript the `+` operator is used for string concatenation, and the `+=` operator for reassigning the string to the same variable. Example:

```
s += ',';
```

Answer (score 1):

use `+=` eg:

```
a = 'Hello'
a += 'World'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var a = "";
 a += "fff";
```